# does MVVM design pattern enforces the ViewModel and View to have a Observable and Observer relationship?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, observer-pattern

I am learning about MVVM design pattern and trying to implement it in Android application at the moment. I am wondering how changes in a ViewModel are reflected in the View. different guides on internet show different things and some of them are suggesting that ViewModel(Observable) should notify changes to View(Observer) rather then Activity/Fragment update the ViewModel and trigger view to update.

What is the correct/best way to implement this? if I my ViewModel is not a Observable then is it that I am not following MVVM properly?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the `View` must be aware of the `ViewModel`, and the `ViewModel` must be aware of the `Model`, but **expose** the `Model` to the `View`. It looks something like this:

View ---*knows about*---> ViewModel ---*knows about*---> Model.

It is **vital** that these arrows stay in this direction, if the `Model` knows about the `ViewModel` then all the nice decoupling is lost.

It is the responsibility of the `ViewModel` to *shout out* when a property has been changed, and anyone listening (your view) should act accordingly.

I'd recommend taking some time going through [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166952/MVVM-in-Android) tutorial.